# @Component and @View Annotation in Angular2

Tags: angular

All:

I am pretty new to Angular2, from some examples, I find that there could be a @Component along with @View, while in others, there is only @Component and the properties(such as template, directives etcs) inside @View will be merged into @Component.

I am not sure if my understanding is right: Is @Component can include @View? If so, why we need a separated @View annotation?

Thanks

Comment: '@View' became optional since angular alpha 39 version.. using @Component would be fine

Answer (score -1):

**update**

`@View()` is about to be removed https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7495

---

It was considered to support multiple views. If you only have one view using `@Component()` alone or `@Component()` and `@View()` is entirely the same. It's not sure if the `@View()` annotation will stay or if they will choose another strategy to implement multiple views.

See also [Proposal: Drop @View decorator](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7363)